# RealityKit add gestures to imported USDZ file

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit, roomplan

I'm running in a problem while trying to add gestures to an imported USDZ file in RealityKit, the model is correctly loaded but I receive this error:

```
// Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: type cast failed
```

The code is:

```
do {
    let entity = try ModelEntity.load(named: "scan")
    newAnchor.addChild(entity)
    entity.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
    uiView.installGestures(.translation, for: entity as! Entity & HasCollision)
    uiView.scene.anchors.append(newAnchor)
} catch {
    print("file not found 2")
}
```

Note that the USDZ file come from RoomPlan API scan.